# In Etrian Odyssey, is there a visual cue for spotting hidden doors?

Tags: etrian-odyssey

I'm specifically referring to Etrian Odyssey 1 on the DS. Is there a visual detail that I should be on the lookout for that marks the location of secret doors? For example a certain colored plant, or detail on the floor, etc.

As I am playing through now, I just use brute force by turning my party towards every wall and looking for the "Check (a)" prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there's no visual indicator of secret passages.

However, since normal secret passages are only one square across, you can use that knowledge to make more educated guesses about where secret passages might be hiding, rather than brute-forcing every wall on the map.

Some good candidates for places to check for secret passages:

- Areas of the map with suspicious amounts of blank space (hidden rooms)
- Areas that border other rooms/hallways from much earlier parts of the level (shortcuts)
- Seemingly-featureless dead ends

After a handful of floors, you should hopefully start to develop a decent sixth sense for the sorts of places that secret passages tend to appear.

Comment: Thankfully, later games tend to have a visual cue on the walls, and standing against & facing a wall typically lets you check it if there's anything there, so it's easier to find two-way passages.